# public static double verifyDouble function not returning

Tags: java, arrays

I have this function, which I made, but it isn't functioning.
Does anyone know, why it doesn't return my error message if I put 5 or a higher number?

```
public static Map randomMap(Homes[] spots){
  System.out.println("Please enter the desired probability");
  System.out.println("NOTE: must be written in decimals, so 50% is 0,5");
  double homeProbability = verifyDouble(input.nextDouble(), 0, 1);

  System.out.println("Please enter the average amount of people in a home");
  int avgPeople = verifyInt(input.nextInt(), 1);

  int randomInt1 = util.randomInt(20)+1;
  int randomInt2 = util.randomInt(20)+1;

  return new Map(randomInt1, randomInt2, spots, homeProbability , avgPeople);
}
```

input.Double reads the input from keyboard.

```
public static double verifyDouble(double num, double min, double max){
do{
  if(num < min && num > max){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between " + min + " and " + max + ":");
    num = input.nextDouble();
  }
}while(num < min && num > max);
return num;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition, `num < min && num > max` does not make sense as `num` can not be less than `min` and greater than `max` at the same time. It should be:

```
num < min || num > max
```

which means `num` is either less than `min` or greater than `max`.

Comment: Maybe they're writing quantum java

Comment: @Arvind Thank you! Of course it doesn't work, when it doesn't make sense, and I've spend hours trying to figure it out - it true, when they say you go blind looking at your own code too long :D

Comment: @ThomasUrupSchjerlund - You are most welcome.